# How to fetch data from Repeater

Tags: asp.net, webforms

When using the following `Repeater`:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptFee" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <div class="CSSTableGenerator">
        <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Course</th>
            <th>Contact_No</th>
            <th>Total_Fee</th>
            <th>Paid_Amount</th>
            <th>Due_Amount</th>

        </thead>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><asp:Label id="lblname" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                 <td><asp:Label id="lblcourse" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Course") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                 <td><asp:Label id="lblcontact" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Contact_No") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                 <td><asp:Label id="lbltotalfee" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Total_Fee") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                 <td><asp:Label id="lblpaid" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Paid_Fee") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                 <td><asp:Label id="lbldue" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Due_Amount") %>'></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
        </div>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The result I'm getting is this:

[image]

Now I want to fetch Abhishek Mishra from repeater. In the `gridView` i was able to do that using `gdFee.Rows[0].Cells[0]`, I am not able to do that in case of a repeater.

How would I retrieve the name of that element at index 0 of a `Repeater`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andy's answer is correct for finding controls while the Repeater is binding each RepeaterItem. If you want to get RepeaterItems outside of any data binding event, the repeater has a RepeaterItem collection simply called `Items`.

Using this would be similar to a GridView, but you would still need to find the control like in Andy's example.

```
RepeaterItem item = rptFee.Items[0];
Label lblname = (Label)item.FindControl("lblname");
string name = lblname.text;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the property OnItemDataBound of you repeater.

In your page:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptFee" runat="server" Visible="false"   OnItemDataBound="rptFee_ItemDataBound">
```

In your code behind:

```
    protected void rptFee_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            Label label = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblname");

            //You have now access to each lblname in your repeater...
            string temp = label.Text;
        }
    }
```

Here's a good link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I dont know exactly what you want to do, you can ask me any question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something below,

```
foreach (RepeaterItem itm in rptFee.Items) {
//You can loop through all repeater items here
    Label lblname = (Label)itm.findControl("lblname");
}
```